Explain how the gpg verification and key obtaining documented in "How to verify your Ubuntu download" is safe against a MITM attack
Some Ubuntu mirror servers still use http instead of https. In addition, a manipulated iso image version with a matching sha256 sum could be foisted on a download server. To ensure tamper-proof and transmission-proof iso images, the servers offer two files: SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg.
SHA256SUMS contains the file names of the offered variants of iso files with the corresponding sha256 sums.
A tutorial suggests to tamper-check these two files like this:

gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
This command verifies SHA256SUMS by the detached signature from SHA256SUMS.gpg and returns the fingerprint and pretended issuer of the key with which the signature had been computed. In my case it still says that it is only an alleged source and nothing indicates that the signature really belongs to the alleged owner.

gpg --keyid-format long --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key ID from previous step, the one without blanks, the whole thing prepended with 0x>


I would like to know why command 2., suggested in How to verify your Ubuntu download, is safe against a man in the middle attack

"Some Ubuntu mirror servers still use http instead of https"  ehm so?! https is not going to fix anything that you believe is wrong with http; same issues will also happen using https. "Wikipedia doesn't say anything about it either." Yes it does.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_server_(cryptographic)  " the servers also offer two files" no not -also-:  the servers offer two files.

@Rinzwind: Sorry, I only searched the German Wikipedia. - Thanks for the link. To my understanding, https uses TLP whereas http does not use any encryption. In the cited Ubuntu tutorial, they say that some mirrors still use http instead of https but this does not harm because of SHA256SUMS.gpg. The tutorial tells how to check SHA256SUMS by SHA256SUMS.gpg using a key to be retrieved from a canonical server is safe against a MIM attack. Therefore my interest, if this step is secure.

@AdalbertHanßen TLP only prevents sniffing not a MITM attack. The way it is setup with a keyserver is as good as it gets. An attacker needs to compromise 2 servers: the one with the ISO and the one holding the hash file. Canonical owns the keyserver so as long as we can trust the maintainer we are as safe as it can get

@Rinzwind: If the iso on the mirror server were tampered and the SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg too (such that the former fits the to be downloaded iso files and  SHA256SUMS.gpg fits SHA256SUMS by virtue of the MITM's counterfit private key), MITM only would have to substitute Canonical's public key by his counterpiece of the counterfit private key in the gpg --keyserver operation. Then the final check of SHA256SUMS would show as trustworthy. Therefore my question: is the whole procedure safe against a MITM-Attack?

@user535733: I think, it would not require to write a book. The crucial step is the command 2 in my post: How is it secure against a MITM attack? In email communications it is common practice to verify the fingerprint of each received public key through means independent from email before using it. Therefore the entries in the key management, whether a key has been certified (i.e. its fingerprint checked independently, the email address verified ans so on),

Let me first preface anything I say here with the fact I'm in the IT Security industry and have been doing that job for over 10 years.  The only way this is mitigated from an MITM attack is if you get your information for hash sums and keys from legitimate sources.  That's the only way to shield against MITM in the download, etc.  Going into detail of how this is done is its own 30-minute training session from the CISSP exam so it's not likely you'll get a super in depth explanation.  I'll write up a far more detailed answer on this later.

Also, you still ask two different questions.  One is validating the the shasums file with cryptographic keys.  The other is "why is getting the keys from X secure'.


OBLIGATORY DISCLAIMER: I am an IT Security professional.  I have been doing ITSec for 10+ years.  The vast majority of this answer is trimmed down from actual explanations and security trainings for brevity, and an entire discussion on this is its own 30-minute-plus security training session (which I charge $250/hour for) so I will not be giving you the full details I'd give in such a presentation.

None of these commands are intrinsically safe from MITM.  The only reason you'd be safe from MITM is if you get your information from trusted sources for keys, etc. for validation.
I won't go into details (as a discussion of how MITM works and how you can be vulnerable to it is its own 30-minute session for the CISSP exam training), but MITM only works if they've already hijacked you.  This is why you have to make sure information you get ahead of time is from legitimate sources for validation.  So, part of your job to protect against MITM is to make sure you're using legitimate sources of information.  And that starts at your computer - making sure you're using proper DNS servers, not using bad DNS servers, that you don't have any rogue hosts file entries for domains, etc.
SO, you have to make sure you have legitimate information.
As of July 7, 2024, the following information is verified legitimate:

The keyserver.ubuntu.com domain resolves to 185.125.188.26 and 185.125.188.27 for IPv4 and 2620:2d:4000:1007::70c and 2620:2d:4000:1007::d43 for IPv6.  If your entries for keyserver.ubuntu.com don't resolve to this, then you're already screwed.

The keys to expect for the SHA256SUMS file are:  (note I have a mirror myself of the Ubuntu releases site/mirror so I pulled this locally, but the origin is from releases.ubuntu.com from a trusted system)
$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: directory '/home/teward/.gnupg' created
gpg: keybox '/home/teward/.gnupg/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 25 13:26:32 2024 EDT
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092


The current information about this key is as follows:
Type: RSA
Bit strength: 4096 bits
RSA Key ID: rsa4096/843938df228d22f7b3742bc0d94aa3f0efe21092
Creation Date: 2012-05-11T22:10:48Z
Comment: Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>


Armed with the key and the SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg you can now validate the key:


$ gpg --keyid-format long --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
gpg: Signature made Thu Apr 25 13:26:32 2024 EDT
gpg:                using RSA key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092
gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
    Primary key fingerprint: 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092

Note that the warning about 'trusted' is only because we do not have the full trust chain and you do not have keys listed from the Signatures on the key that are trusted to you that indicate this is the legitimate key.  That's why it's crucial to get your data from a trusted source so you KNOW you're working with legitimate data and not bogus data.
Note, however, I'm showing you the output from a system that is not my primary Linux system. My primary linux system has GPG keys stored in its keyring from various Ubuntu developers, Debian developers, etc. who I have vetted myself or have gotten to know and met over the years, and on my system the key does NOT show this warning because the trusted signers I already know have signed the package signing key. Because of the keys I know from others being marked as Trusted in my GPG keyrings, validation of the signing key on my actual machine shows Trusted, and the warning you see and I mentioned in my example above, the 'web of trust' from those signatures enhances and validates the trustworthyness of the key.
The only way to make sure you're protected from MITM is trusting the sources of data you are using to get your information and keys from and verifying the legitimate source.  There is no other intrinsic MITM protections anywhere at play.

I have checked the IPv4-Part of 1 (same result as you). After following various steps from the tutorial, the signing key has the fingerprint 8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092, which is the same as provided by the second one under the headline "The Ubuntu ISO Images are signed with keys:" in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#GPG_Keys_used_by_Ubuntu. I verified it using a https connection. This fingerprint - leaving out the interspersed blanks - is exactly what is in your listings after "RSA Key ID: rsa4096/". Did I forget anything important then?

@AdalbertHanßen nope.  If the key matches the key stated in the tutorial, Security Team documentation, and the output and key data I have above, you're all set.  No MITM on you!
